# How to add image in google chart

Tags: json, image, charts, organization

```
function test()
{
$array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'string');
$array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'string');
$array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'string');

$array['rows'][] = array('c' => array( array('v'=>'Name'), array('v'=>22)) );
$array['rows'][] = array('c' => array( array('v'=>'Name1'), array('v'=>26)));
$array['rows'][] = array('c' => array( array('v'=>'Name2'), array('v'=>12)));

return $array;
}
print json_encode(test());
```

I am using above code to build organization chart in using google chart. I want to add image and designation with name. Could you please tell me how can i modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried to solve your problem.

We can use  **{allowHtml:true}** to embed and process HTML code with Google chart.

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Parent');

    data.addRows([
        [{
            v: 'parent_node',
            f: 'Parent Node'
        },
        null],
        [{
            v: 'child_node_1',
            f: '<b>Child Node</b> <img src="http://www.mapsysinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/oracle-logo.gif" height="42" width="50"> </img>'
        }, 'parent_node'],
        [{
            v: 'child_node_2',
            f: 'Child Node'
        }, 'parent_node']
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        allowHtml: true
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['orgchart'],
    callback: drawChart
});
```

Here I created Example Please check it: https://jsfiddle.net/1gvwLy8n/5/